# Virtual environment confusion

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, virtualenv, python-venv

i've created some virtual environment called timeseries. there is no library called in it right now, except for pip and setuptools.
now i go on to jupyter and select this kernel, and run "pip list". to my surprise, i see all the packages in my general python3 kernel.
i've searched on the google but nothing to be found.
Please help, this is really driving me mad

[image: virtual environment now showing right packages]

**EDIT**:
i'm trying different combinations, one of which is: i activated the virtual env in cmd, and started jupyter there, and went into the folder where the vir.env. is, run "!pip list", and i saw the packages i was supposed to see, but went on investigating, then run 2 commands that are below. how come is this possible?

[image]

Comment: Maybe your new virtuale v is sharong the global sitepackage

Comment: Use the --no-site-packages flag to prevent this virtualenv from “seeing” your global Python “site-packages” directory, so that our experiments aren’t confused by any Python packages you happen to already have installed globally.... [Taked from: https://the-hitchhikers-guide-to-packaging.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pip.html]

Comment: thanks for the reply efirvida, actualy i created the ve with venv, not virtualenv. so it doesnt  parameter as you suggest. but what it has is, "include-system-site-packages = false" key in pyenv.cfg file, which, i belive, functions as your suggestion. what else could it be?

Comment: i did the same with virtualenv, and still the same result. by the way, --no-site-packages is depreciated and not having the access to site packages is the default behaviour

Comment: Sorry, I just answer using my memory, and with the first link that I found about `--no-site-packages`. I currently use pipenv to create my virtual environments which is much better take a look here https://realpython.com/pipenv-guide/

Comment: thanks but i just want to understand what the problem is and honestly i dont believe pipenv would be a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I've found the solution. this is so weird, coz nobody has mentioned this so far.
the thing is, one is supposed to install the jupyter as well within the virtual environment and launch it from command line when the virtual environment is active.